# Delphi print memo to zebra printer

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I need help.
I have this code to print by zebra, and it prints nothing.

```
  procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
    var
    cm: AnsiString;
    zpl : TStringList;
    p: TPrinter;
    i: integer;
    begin
    p := Printer;
    zpl := TStringList.Create;
    memo2.Lines.Add('^XA');
    memo2.Lines.Add('^LH5,5');
    memo2.Lines.Add(concat ('^FO50,20^ADN,36,20^FD', edit1.text,'^FS'));
    memo2.Lines.Add(concat ('^FO35,60^ADN,15,10^FD', edit4.text,'^FS'));
    memo2.Lines.Add(concat ('^FO50,115^BCN,60,N,N,N^FD', edit1.text, '^FS'));
    memo2.Lines.Add('^XZ');
    zpl.AddStrings (memo2.lines);
    p.BeginDoc;
    for i := 0 to memo2.Lines.Count-1 do
    begin
    zpl.Assign(memo2.lines);
    end;
    p.EndDoc
    end;
```

thank you to help me
I know to print the lines as a text, but I need to send these lines as command to Zebra printer.

Comment: It prints nothing, because the code doesn't perform any printing.

Comment: That seems a bit harsh.  True but doesn't help him much unless he rereads the example code in the help, which is where I am assuming he got most of the code.  Denn, what I think you might be missing is that the TPrinter uses a default TCanvas and actually prints an image of what ever is on the canvas.  So if you put the text on the canvas it will send it when EndDoc is called.  At least that is what it says in the help files it has been so long since I have had to print anything, I try to avoid it at all costs.

Comment: @AlienHeadDiscs Harsh?! What else can be said? All the code does is populate a memo control. What the asker presumably wants to do is to send this text direct to the printer. A canvas won't help. Perhaps the asker expects us to work that out and is really asking, "how do I send data direct to the printer, bypassing the driver?" If that is so, then the asker should ask that. However, that question has been asked many times before.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan harsh might be the wrong word, but your comment isn't helpful, as obviously it doesn't print, just as the title suggests ..

Comment: @JohnEasley The original question read as though the asker was expecting something to be printed.

Comment: You are correct, I apologize and I should have looked closer before typing.  I also want to thank you and all the others that spend hours a day answering these questions.  I agree that most of the questions that are asked can be answered with just a little effort of research, either searching what has previously been asked but more importantly in the help files and tutorials of the system they are working in.  I mentioned the Canvas mainly because his code looked identical to what is in the delphi help file except a string list was substituted for the canvas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of options. You can open the printer in `RAW` mode and write those commands using  `WritePrinter()`. There is a non-working example [here](http://codeverge.com/embarcadero.delphi.general/print-barcode-on-zebra-lp-2824-pri/1056082) and below:

```
uses
  Printers, WinSpool;

procedure Print;
var 
  ADevice, ADeviceName, ADevicePort: array[0..255]of Char;
  PrinterHandle: THandle
  DocInfo: TDocInfo1;
  dwJob: cardinal;
  dwBytesWritten: cardinal;
  AUtf8: UTF8string;
  ADeviceMode: THandle;
begin
  //your printer (a windows generic printer works fine)
  Printer.PrinterIndex := LocalPrinterIndex; 
  Printer.GetPrinter(ADevice, ADeviceName, ADevicePort, ADeviceMode);

  //Need a handle to the printer
  if not OpenPrinter(ADevice, FPrinterHandle, nil) then 
    Exit;

  //Fill in the structure with info about this "document"
  DocInfo.pDocName := PChar('Spooler Document Name');
  DocInfo.pOutputFile := nil;
  DocInfo.pDatatype := 'RAW';

  //Inform the spooler the document is beginning
  dwJob := StartDocPrinter(PrinterHandle, 1, @DocInfo);
  if dwJob = 0 then 
  begin
    ClosePrinter(PrinterHandle);
    FPrinterHandle := 0;
    Exit;
  end;

  //Start a page
  if not StartPagePrinter(PrinterHandle) then 
  begin
    EndDocPrinter(PrinterHandle);
    ClosePrinter(PrinterHandle);
    FPrinterHandle := 0;
    Exit;
  end;

  //your zebra code... 
  AUtf8 := UTF8string('Hello world');
  WritePrinter(PrinterHandle, @AUtf8[1], Length(AUtf8), dwBytesWritten);

  //End the page
  if not EndPagePrinter(PrinterHandle) then 
  begin
    EndDocPrinter(PrinterHandle);
    ClosePrinter(PrinterHandle);
    FPrinterHandle := 0;
    Exit;
  end;

  //Inform the spooler that the document is ending
  if not EndDocPrinter(PrinterHandle) then 
  begin
    ClosePrinter(PrinterHandle);
    FPrinterHandle := 0;
    Exit;
  end;

  //Tidy up the printer handle
  ClosePrinter(PrinterHandle);
  FPrinterHandle := 0;
end;
```

Or you can install a Generic Text Only driver for that printer and print using old fashioned Pascal WriteLn calls, as described [here](http://embarcadero.newsgroups.archived.at/public.delphi.language.delphi.win32/201102/11021411430.html). You will need to create a `SelectPrinter()` method of your own. Included below:

```
procedure PrintLabel(LabelCommands: TStringList);
var
  F: TextFile;
  I: Integer;
begin
  SelectPrinter('LABEL PRINTER');

  AssignPrn(F);
  ReWrite(F);

  for I := 0 to LabelCommands.Count - 1 do
    WriteLn(F,LabelCommands[I]);

  CloseFile(F);
end;
```

Comment: Take care with casting the string to UTF8String if your strings are already UTF8 encoded, like a returned label from a parcel service. You can end up with double encoded text.