# Print ZPL file to Zebra printer results into ASCII dump

Tags: delphi, printing, zpl, zebra

I am trying to send a ZPL file to a Zebra printer, but the contents of the file are being printed as ASCII text without being interpreted.

I have tried some of the solutions provided in the following Stackoverflow threads, but none of them seem to work:

[Delphi printing to Zebra printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198820/delphi-printing-to-zebra-printer)

[Sending commands directly to Zebra EPL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16969323/sending-commands-directly-to-zebra-epl?lq=1)

[Delphi print memo to zebra printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29896651/delphi-print-memo-to-zebra-printer)

Note that the ZPL file is provided to us by the parcel service, and I am not sure if the problems I am experiencing are related to the UTF8 encoded strings mentioned in one of the threads.

I am using Delphi 11.3.

Any ideas?

Comment: I use Delphi to print ZPL labels too. The code I use looks similar to [the answer by Joelend here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25371291/print-a-string-directly-to-printer). Note the `Documento.pDataType := 'RAW';`. My code is old, so I'm not sure if this is helpful for Delphi 11.3.

Comment: What model is the Zebra printer? How are you sending the ZPL file (Windows print? Raw TCP/IP? FTP?)? And can you include the ZPL in your question? ZPL should start with `^XA` (Start Format) and end with `^XZ` (End Format).

Comment: Which printer driver do you use? Because it is enough to use a generic text printer driver!

Comment: By the way, if you want to try to include a preview feature in your app, you can use my lib from https://github.com/TheDelphiCoder/Zebra (VCL only!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed another instance of the printer and used the ‘generic/text’ driver only.

Finally, this small code fragment did the job:

```
var
  F: TextFile;
  I: Integer;
begin
  Printer.PrinterIndex := ComboBox1.ItemIndex;
  AssignPrn(F);
  ReWrite(F);
  for I := 0 to FileToPrint.Count - 1 do
    WriteLn(F, FileToPrint[I]);
  CloseFile(F);
end;
```

Note:

- ComboBox1 contains the printers available in Windows. It was populated by using `ComboBox1.Items := Printer.Printers;`
- FileToPrint is a TStringList, containing the actual ZPL file by using `FileToPrint.LoadFromFile(OpenDialog1.FileName);`

Thank you, [KIKO Software](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3986005/kiko-software), [Dale M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2335446/dale-m), and [Delphi Coder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11329562/delphi-coder), for your comments. Your feedback helped me explore some paths that I had not considered before. As a result, I decided to install an additional printer instance using the ‘generic/text’ driver.